# loop ajax calls to fill multiple divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got two divs on my page

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

That I'm trying to dynamically fill with the following php call.

```
<script>
    var queries = ["SELECT * from table1", "SELECT * from table2"]

    for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "querySQL.php",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            data: {query: queries[i]},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#" + i).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

It looks like it's looping through the queries properly, however it 'erases' the first one and when I view the page, only the results of the second query remain.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting your queries in javascript, remember the whole world can read them.

Comment: I would recommend you to make one ajax request and get data for all divs in an array.

Comment: var queries = ["SELECT * from table1, SELECT * from table2"] is an array with only one element. I guess it should be:  var queries = ["SELECT * from table1", "SELECT * from table2"]

Comment: this is for use in an internal application, so the whole world won't see it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notwithstanding the warnings about exposing a raw SQL interface in your API, the problem you have is that `i` in the callback once the AJAX call completes doesn't have the same value it did when you initiated the call.

The easiest solution is to use `$.each` or `Array#forEach` instead of a `for` loop, and use the `index` parameter that is then correctly bound to the current value in the callback:

```
$.each(queries, function(i, query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "querySQL.php",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { query: query },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#" + (i + 1)).html(data);  // NB: i starts at 0, not 1
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is for an internal use website in a very small company so I'm not too concerned about exposing the raw SQL interface.  However, I assume as a general guideline, this should be placed within the php script?

Comment: @Constantino yes, absolutely you shouldn't expose your SQL directly to the web interface.  Someone might subvert your page and send `DELETE * FROM table1`.

Comment: @Constantino p.s. whilst completely numeric IDs are permitted in HTML5, they're _not_ permitted in CSS3, so you could never add an ID-specific style to your content like this.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips.  I've moved the SQL to php and adjusted the IDs to not be completely numeric.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
 var queries = ["SELECT * from table1", "SELECT * from table2"];

       function callAjax(i){
            $.ajax({
                url: "querySQL.php",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                data: {query: queries[i]},
                success: function(data) {
                   console.log(i)
                    $("#" + (i+1).html(data);
                }
            });
    }
       for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {

         callAjax(i)  

        }
```

Comment: no it won't - you're not referencing the right elements of the `queries` array.

Comment: I can assure you it doesn't.   The code you've written here cannot possibly access `queries[0]`

Comment: better now, but it would be cleaner to pass both the current query and the index to the `callAjax` function, making that function completely independent of the `queries` variable from the outer scope.   Once you've done that then the code is semantically equivalent to my `.each` based method.

Comment: yep i agree but in this case "queries" is within the scope of what the dev has written so dint do that so kept it straight forward.  I do agree that what you have done is the best approach as he is using jQuery.

Comment: That's true, but by making the query a parameter instead of using the scoped variable it makes the function more useful by making it independent of the `queries` array.  There's good time and place to use outer scope variables, but IMHO this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have only 2 results. The problem here is your var i. it starts with i=0 and ends in i=1. So only div $("#" + 0).html(data) and $("#" + 1).html(data).

To fix this start with

```
i=1; i <= queries.length; i++
```

Comment: that's a minor problem, but it's not the biggest one he has.

Comment: that is the major issue since his divs are not matching. Thats why it is not showing one of them

Comment: even if he fixes that, only one of his divs will get filled because of how `i` is handled in the async callbacks.  Also, as written your code won't even pull the queries out of the array properly (since the array indexes do of course start from 0)

Comment: yes agree with you the query needs to start with 0. but not sure what you meant by async i. it is always here in sync even in your solution. i will be zero in first success and one in second success?

Comment: no, because in a `for` loop because the AJAX calls are async then `i` will already be equal to 2 before any of the callbacks ever get called.  My version with `i` bound to a function parameter doesn't have that problem because that forces the _current_ value of `i` to be bound, not its future value.

Answer (score -1):

i guess you need to send only one request on page load.And in your php file that is ajax url,you need to execute the both queries one by one and then populate data in the div in the same file.and just return all data.On ajax success,you just populate a div with returned data.

Comment: this is not an answer to the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

I would set the `datatype` to `application/json`, so the answer can be a json object, not only text/html. I would return the following parameters from the php as a json via `json_encode`, something like this:

```
{firstResult:{divToUse: "#1", dataToFill: "#1 content"}, 
 secondResult:{divToUse: "#2", dataToFill: "#2 content"},
 ....
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: an AJAX API should never assume that it knows anything about the layout of the page that's going to consume it.

Comment: @Alnitak but he has 2 exact divs, that he wants to fill dinamycally. Also, if the html is generated on the fly, you can return it as an element of the json. I don't know why did you downvoted the answer, I gave, it only describes a possible method. If you didn't notice, the code is a returned JSON object from php, that could even be generated automatically, so I don't really get the point of your downvote. But thx.

Comment: The downvote is because this is _poor design_.  What if the API is going to be used on a different page that doesn't use the same IDs?  It's the job of the client-side JS to decide which divs to fill, not the job of the server.